# Audi A6 2016 sometimes high rpm and not running right

Tags: diesel, audi, a6

Recently I've purchased Audi A6 3.0TDI 272hp 2016 and sometimes the car starts at 800rpms and sometimes slightly above that - let say 850. The car runs fine when it is keeping 800 rpms at idle, however if it starts at 850 rpms it is slow and sluggish. Fuel consumption is higher when at 820 rpms. Any ideas?

Comment: Is the ambient temperature lower when it starts at 850?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Ambient temperature is about 15 degrees celsius. Even after 20km driving with engine on 90 degrees is still holding at 850 rpms.